# Google Play: Limit distribution to these carriers

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I published my app about 12 hours ago. The web play store still says "This app is incompatible with all of your devices". After a great deal of reading, I still come up with nothing. So I go look under "Pricing and Distribution" for my country "United States". I clicked on show uptions, and I found [image]

My phone is Samsung Galaxy S5 and carrier is T-Mobile. I don't believe there is an explanation here for why my app is incompatible, any thoughts?

Comment: Also I used the phone for testing the app during development, and I had no problem with it.

Comment: Also my app has ads by AdMob. Would that cause my phone not to be able to download the app since it is a test phone?

Comment: Rather than carrier distribution, I think it's more likely your device is incompatible because of os version or features. Share your manifest and what device are you using?

Comment: If it were os then it should not have worked during development, no? My phone is Lollipop and my gradle is `minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23`

Comment: It still could be other features, can't tell without actual device and manifest though.